# How to find rank using raw query laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, syntax-error, rank

I want to query rank in database with laravel but doesn't work

SQL Query (It's Works)

```
SELECT
    'id',
    'name',
    'local_pic',
    'point',
    FIND_IN_SET( 'point', ( SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( 'point' ORDER BY 'point' DESC )
        FROM 'students' )) AS rank
FROM 'students'
ORDER BY rank
```

And I try to use

```
$top_students = DB::table('students')
    ->select('id','name','local_pic','point',
    ->whereRaw("find_in_set('point',( SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( 'point' ORDER BY 'point' DESC ) FROM 'students' )) as rank"))
   ->orderBy('rank','DESC')
   ->get();
```

-

```
$top_students = DB::select("SELECT 'id','name','local_pic','point', FIND_IN_SET( 'point', ( SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( 'point' ORDER BY 'point' DESC ) FROM 'students' )) AS rank FROM 'students' ORDER BY rank");
```

It call syntax error, how can I solve this

Comment: use DB::select("SELECT 'id','name','local_pic','point', FIND_IN_SET( 'point', ( SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( 'point' ORDER BY 'point' DESC ) FROM 'students' )) AS rank FROM 'students' ORDER BY rank");

Comment: Your raw query does not make sense to me.  Can you add some sample data to your question?

Comment: have you tried your query in the database itself?

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
$top_students = DB::table('students')
              ->select('id','name','local_pic','point')
              ->selectRaw("find_in_set('point',( SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( 'point' ORDER BY 'point' DESC ) FROM 'students' )) as rank")
              ->orderBy('rank','DESC')
              ->get();
```

you missed some ending brackets, now the syntax errors fixed, next you can check your query by changing the `->get()` to `->toSql()`

Comment: This is wrong. Your `whereRaw` doesn't make sense. Check his original raw sql.

Comment: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''students' )) as rank order by `rank` desc' at line 1 (SQL: select `id`, `name`, `local_pic`, `point` from `students` where find_in_set('point',( SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( 'point' ORDER BY 'point' DESC ) FROM 'students' )) as rank order by `rank` desc)

Comment: @anan I corrected the php/laravel syntax error, also you can change the whereRaw to selectRaw to get the sql result. It's actually the error in SQL query, so first you correct that

Comment: @IjasAmeenudeen yes you are correct, I am on a hurry to correct the syntax error in Laravel, so I missed it, thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 0):

Your raw SQL doesn't include a where statement. Also, you are using `whereRaw()` to add a raw selection query, which is wrong.

Try:

```
\DB::table('students')
    ->select(
        'id',
        'name',
        'local_pic',
        'point',
        \DB::raw("FIND_IN_SET( 'point', ( SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( 'point' ORDER BY 'point' DESC ) FROM 'students' )) AS rank")
    )
    ->orderBy('rank', 'DESC')
    ->get();
```

Or

```
\DB::table('students')
    ->selectRaw("
        id,
        name,
        local_pic,
        point,
        FIND_IN_SET( 'point', ( SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( 'point' ORDER BY 'point' DESC ) FROM 'students' )) AS rank
    ")
    ->orderBy('rank', 'DESC')
    ->get();
```

Comment: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''students' )) AS rank from `students` order by `rank` desc' at line 6 (SQL: select id, name, local_pic, point, FIND_IN_SET( 'point', ( SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( 'point' ORDER BY 'point' DESC ) FROM 'students' )) AS rank from `students` order by `rank` desc)

Comment: Are you sure your raw sql works. Check this http://snippi.com/s/6hew1ty . your sql and generated one are same.

Comment: Oh, fix that and follow the answers I provided.

Comment: Is it possible to `order` or `where` an alias (`rank`) in the same context or the same level as the `where` clause? Perhaps you meant a subquery and `where` on it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DB::select("
    SELECT
        'id',
        'name',
        'local_pic',
        'point',
        FIND_IN_SET( 'point', ( SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( 'point' ORDER BY 'point' DESC )
            FROM 'students' )) AS rank
    FROM 'students'
    ORDER BY rank
");
```

Comment: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''students' )) AS rank FROM 'students' ORDER BY rank' at line 7 (SQL: SELECT 'id', 'name', 'local_pic', 'point', FIND_IN_SET( 'point', ( SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( 'point' ORDER BY 'point' DESC ) FROM 'students' )) AS rank FROM 'students' ORDER BY rank )

Comment: There is issue with your query not in converting to `laravel`. What database you are using?